# Given a list of words, How to put them into "Families"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating an evil hangman game using python and I'm stuck. I'm trying to figure out how to put words into families. For example, suppose I have a list

```
ALLY BETA COOL DEAL ELSE FLEW GOOD HOPE IBEX
```

Every word falls into one of a few families based on where the E is:

```
- - - -, containing ALLY, COOL, GOOD
- E - -, containing BETA and DEAL
- - E -, containing FLEW and IBEX
E - - E, containing ELSE
- - - E, containing HOPE.
```

Is there a way to use a dictionary to help map out what words belong in what families? Our class hasn't gotten to talk about dictionaries yet, but I read ahead and believe it's possible. The file i'm using is around 170,000 words, but above is just a simple example.

Comment: are they all 4 letter words?

Comment: When you say 'families' what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import groupby

words = ['ALLY', 'BETA', 'COOL', 'DEAL', 'ELSE', 'FLEW', 'GOOD', 'HOPE', 'IBEX']
e_locs = sorted(([c == 'E' for c in w], i) for i, w in enumerate(words))
result = [[words[i] for x, i in g] for k, g in groupby(e_locs, lambda x: x[0])]
```

Result:

```
>>> result
[['ALLY', 'COOL', 'GOOD'], ['HOPE'], ['FLEW', 'IBEX'], ['BETA', 'DEAL'], ['ELSE']]
```

Here is a version that also keeps track of where the Es are:

```
words = ['ALLY', 'BETA', 'COOL', 'DEAL', 'ELSE', 'FLEW', 'GOOD', 'HOPE', 'IBEX']
result = {}
for word in words:
    key = ' '.join('E' if c == 'E' else '-' for c in word)
    if key not in result:
        result[key] = []
    result[key].append(word)
```

Result:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(result)
{'- - - -': ['ALLY', 'COOL', 'GOOD'],
 '- - - E': ['HOPE'],
 '- - E -': ['FLEW', 'IBEX'],
 '- E - -': ['BETA', 'DEAL'],
 'E - - E': ['ELSE']}
```

To choose the biggest family (using the first version, where `result` is a list of lists):

```
>>> max(result, key=len)
['ALLY', 'COOL', 'GOOD']
```

To choose the biggest family using the second version you can just use `result.values()` instead of `result`, or to get a tuple with the E locations and the family you could use the following:

```
>>> max(result.items(), key=lambda k_v: len(k_v[1]))
('- - - -', ['ALLY', 'COOL', 'GOOD'])
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks so much. Now if I wanted to choose the biggest family, how would I go about that?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, how would you go about choosing the biggest family in the second version?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: from itertools import groupby

In [2]: import string

In [3]: words = "ALLY BETA COOL DEAL ELSE FLEW GOOD HOPE IBEX".split()

In [4]: table = string.maketrans('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
   ...:                          '????E?????????????????????')

In [5]: f = lambda w: w.translate(table)

In [6]: for k,g in groupby(sorted(words, key=f), f):
   ...:     print k, list(g)
   ...:     
???? ['ALLY', 'COOL', 'GOOD']
???E ['HOPE']
??E? ['FLEW', 'IBEX']
?E?? ['BETA', 'DEAL']
E??E ['ELSE']

# to get the biggest group
In [7]: max((list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(words, key=f), f)), key=len)
Out[7]: ['ALLY', 'COOL', 'GOOD']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular exprssions you could do something like this:

```
import re

def into_families(words):
    # here you could add as many families as you want
    families = {
                '....': re.compile('[^E]{4}'),
                '...E': re.compile('[^E]{3}E'),
                '..E.': re.compile('[^E]{2}E[^E]'),
                '.E..': re.compile('[^E]E[^E]{2}'),
                'E..E': re.compile('E[^E]{2}E'),
    }
    return dict((k, [w for w in words if r.match(w)]) for k, r in families.items())
```

Or if you want to create the regular expressions dynamically:

```
def into_families(words):
    family_names = set(''.join('E' if x == 'E' else '.' for x in w) for w in words)
    families = dict((x, re.compile(x.replace('.', '[^E]'))) for x in family_names)
    return dict((k, [w for w in words if r.match(w)]) for k, r in families.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

words = 'ALLY BETA COOL DEAL ELSE FLEW GOOD HOPE IBEX'.split()

groups = defaultdict(list)

for word in words:
    indices = tuple(m.start() for m in re.finditer('E', word))
    groups[indices].append(word)

for k, v in sorted(groups.items()):
    tpl = ['E' if i in k else'-' for i in range(4)]
    print ' '.join(tpl), ' '.join(v)
```