# List: How to create a new list from a Max Count

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
def validateGuess():
    print(letters)
    inputGuess= input("Choose one of the letters above:")
    return inputGuess

def wordLength():
    length=input("Welcome to Hangman. How many letters in the secret word?")
    length1=int(length)
    if length1 <0:
        length=input("Welcome to Hangman. How many letters in the secret word?")
    return length    

def guessAmount():
    guesses=input("How many guesses would you like?")
    guesses1=int(guesses)
    if guesses1 < 0:
        guesses=input("How many guesses would you like?")
    return guesses

welcome=wordLength()
remain=input("Do you want to print the count of how many words remain [Y/N]?")
guessNumber=int(guessAmount())
F=open('dictionary.txt')
F1=F.readlines()

welcome2=int(welcome)
a_list=[word.strip('\n') for word in F1]
possible_words = [x for x in a_list if len(x) == welcome2]

letters= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

while guessNumber >0:
    letter_guess=validateGuess()
    letters.remove(letter_guess)
    guessNumber -= 1
    result={}
    for word in possible_words:
        key=' '.join(letter_guess if c == letter_guess else '-' for c in word)
        if key not in result:
            result[key]=[]
        result[key].append(word)
    inverse= [(len(value), key) for key, value in result.items()]
    Answer=max(inverse)[1]
    possible_words=result.values()
    print()
```

I'm writing a program in Python called Evil Hangman. Basically, given a list of 170,000 words, I have to make it as hard as possible for the user to win. So for each user guess, such as "A", I put the words into families based on where "A" appears in the words, and then select the **largest family** and print where "A" appears in that family. This goes on for however long the user decides. My problem is I can't figure out a way to create a new list of words for my while loop to go through. This new list would contain only the words in the **largest family**.I thought,

```
for word in max(result):
     possible_words+=word
```

would work but I can't figure out why it doesn't. Any and all help is much appreciated. Also, I'm new to Python and did my best explaining my problem, but if you have any questions don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Please do not use the python-2.7 tag for questions about python 3.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the code it looks like you can change the end of your while loop from this:

```
Answer=max(inverse)[1]
possible_words=result.values()
```

To this:

```
Answer=max(inverse)[1]
possible_words=result[Answer]
```

Since `Answer` will be the key from `result` that gives you the largest family, `result[Answer]` will be that largest family and you can just reassign `possible_words` to that value.

Comment: Better yet, do this [the more efficient way from my answer to the question this method was given to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15976560/722121), and then the part he wants is right there.

Comment: Or [the same efficient way from my answer to the question that created the data in the first place](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15937127/505154) :)

Comment: Wow, I'm not going to bother answering any more questions for this guy, if he's clearly not taking on-board the advice being given and - by the amount being posted - really not trying to do stuff by himself.

Comment: Yep, I came to the same conclusion when I saw your comment.